# How to determine which kind of the authentication is using in a ms sql connection from c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Is there a way in ADO to get which kind of authentication is using by ms sql connection?
If we are using Windows Authentication, or SQL Authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to parse the connection string and check the `UseIntegratedSecurity` or `UserName` properties.